# Lagrange Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems proceeding in solving the following differential equation $$xy' + y + (y')^2 = 0.$$

After solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the quadratic and using the substitution $u^2 = x^2 - 4y$ in the discriminant, I obtain $\frac{du}{dx} = 2 \frac{x}{u} -1$. Please how can I proceed?

Comment: Looking at WA's output for both of these equations, I'm not sure how nice of a result you expect to get here...

Comment: @Ian, I seem not to get what you are trying to say! OK, probably I have used a vague substitution. Could any one propose a better one?

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean that the solution given in Wolfram Alpha is actually quite sophisticated; my guess would be that it involves solving some nontrivial cubic equation, or something like this. So I don't see what you expect to get through this hand calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy+y+y’^2=0$$
Let :  $y’=p$
$$y=-xy’-y’^2=-xp-p^2$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dp} =-p\frac{dx}{dp}-x-2p$$
$$p=y’=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dp} \frac{dp}{dx} =-p-(x+2p) \frac{dp}{dx}$$
$$2p=-(x+2p) \frac{dp}{dx}$$
$$2p\frac{dx}{dp}+x=-2p$$
The solution of this first order linear ODE is :
$$x=-\frac{2}{3}p+\frac{C}{2\sqrt{p}}$$
$$y=-xp -p^2= \frac{2}{3}p^2-\frac{C}{2}\sqrt{p} –p^2 =-\frac{1}{3}p^2-\frac{C}{2}\sqrt{p}$$
Finally, the solution of $xy+y+y’^2=0$ expressed on parametric form with parameter $p$ is :
$$\begin{cases}
    x=-\frac{2}{3}p+ \frac{C}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{p} }     \\
    y =-\frac{1}{3}p^2-\frac{C}{2}\sqrt{p} \\
  \end{cases}$$
If one want to find the explicit function $y(x)$ the parameter $p$ has to be eliminated from the system $\left(x(p),y(p)\right)$. This is possible, but will lead to complicated equations.

Comment: This is a good hint. However, obtaining the explicit solution would be far better regardless of it´s complexity!!!!!!!

Comment: @KaRJXEN Parametrizing by $r=\sqrt{p}$ instead of $p$ and replacing $C/2$ with just $C$, the first equation is $x=-2r^2/3+C/r$ and the second is $y=-r^4/3-Cr$. The easiest thing to do would be to solve for $r$ in terms of $x$ and substitute that into the equation for $y$. But that means you must solve $rx=-2r^3/3+C$, which is a nontrivial cubic equation (as I pointed out earlier today). It can be done...but the solution is so horrible that I don't see why it is desirable.

Comment: @Ian, OK! Guess I am gon have to opt for writing my solution in terms of a parameter!

Answer (score 0):

First make the substitution $p=y'$ to get  $$px+y+p^2=0$$
Now differentiate wrt $x$ $$p'x+2p+2pp'=0$$
$$p'=\frac{-2p}{x+2p}$$
Put $p=vx\implies p'=v+xv'$
$$v+xv'=\frac{-2v}{1+2v}$$
$$xv'=\frac{-3v-2v^2}{1+2v}$$
$$\frac{1+2v}{3v+2v^2}dv=-\frac{dx}x$$
Now integrating,
$$\ln v+2\ln(2v+3)+3\ln x=c$$
Now put back $v=\frac px$ to get
$$\ln p+2\ln(2p+3x)=c\implies p(2p+3x)^2=c$$
I have no idea how to solve that last equation but I think someone else might be able to do it.

Comment: That explains where WA's cubic formula came from. But then still after *that* you have to integrate $p$ to get $y$.

Comment: @Ian what cubic formula are you talking about? Giving the original DE to W|A spits out only non-understandable gibberish.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the "gibberish" is indeed a cubic formula result. It may be easier to see this in the substituted form that the OP gave. The point is, taking your work as given, you have $4p^3+12xp^2+9x^2p-c=0$, so that for each $x$, $p$ is given by the solution to some cubic equation; then $y$ is the antiderivative of that.

Comment: Oh. If you dont mind me asking @Ian ,how can I solve that last equation I got?

Comment: The cubic formula is the best we can do (again assuming no errors on your part). I find it remarkable that the result of that cubic formula even has an elementary antiderivative (in the strict sense of "elementary").

Comment: @G-man. If you don´t mind, could you please obtain the solution in terms of $y$ as a function of $x$

Comment: @KaRJXEN In all seriousness: I'm pretty sure you can't, at least not in a nice form with elementary functions. There might be a nice series solution, but the elementary solution, as best I can tell, will always be in a horrible form (the antiderivative of the solution to a cubic equation with variable coefficients).

Comment: @Ian, Thanks. Could you suggest some text I could try out, guys? as in reference material for solving Lagrange equations

Comment: @KaRJXEN What exactly do you mean by "Lagrange equations"? (Lagrange did so much math that attaching his name to something doesn't really clarify anything.) Does this arise as an Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: I read in this text that I am using that the differential equation of the format $y = xf(y´) + g(y´)$ is called a Lagrange differential equation, some times a generalization of Clairaut differential equation. Isn´t it so? Sorry but that´s what I meant!!!!