# Why is solution to Lagrange differential equation expressed in terms of $y'$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Lagrange differential equation is of the following type: $y=x\varphi(y')+\psi(y')$
We can solve the equation by setting $y'=p$ and differentiating with respect to x. We get the general solution and sometimes a singular solution.
The general solution is of the following form:
$x=f(p,C)$
$y=f(p,C)\varphi(p)+\psi(p)$

If $p=y'$, I don't see why this is called a solution. Isn't this another differential equation we are supposed to solve, just like $y=y'$ ? Isn't solution a family of functions dependend only on $x$?

Comment: No, you let $y'=p$ to solve the differential equation. No one says that it is called a solution, and you have the general solution written down.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425433/lagrange-differential-equation) for example.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the comment.